# Segmentation fault in a list with memcpy

Tags: c, list, memcpy

I'm trying to copy a list into another list with memcpy, but I'm getting a segmentation fault everytime I try to access the value I copied.

I've already tried moving pointers around, but the problem still occurs.
create_list creates a new head node for the list and returns it. Here is some of the code:

```
/* The n variable shows the number of elements in the list for the head */
struct list {
    union{
        void *data;
        struct {
            unsigned num;
            List *end;
        };
    };
    List *node;
};
List *
create_list()
{
    List *head;

    head = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    head->num = 0;
    head->end = NULL;
    head->node = NULL;

    return head;
}
int
cpy_list(List *l1, List **l2)
{
    List *iter;
    void *data_aux;

    *l2 = create_list();
    iter = l1->node;
    while (iter != l1->end) {
        memcpy(&data_aux, iter->data, sizeof(iter->data));
        //printf("data_aux: %s\n", data_aux);
        insert_list(*l2, data_aux, NULL);
        //printf("iter->data: %s\n", iter->data);
        iter = iter->node;
    }

    return 1;
}

void
print_list(List *head)
{
    List *iter;
    iter = head->node;
    printf("[");
    while (iter != head->end) {
        printf("\"%s\",", iter->data);
        iter = iter->node;
    }
    printf("\"%s\"", iter->data);
    printf("]");
    printf("\n");
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    List *l1, *l2;
    char *str[] = {"Test0", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"};
    void *data_aux;
    l1 = create_list();

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        insert_list(l1 ,str[k], NULL);
    }
    printf("l1: ");
    print_list(l1);

    cpy_list(l1, &l2);
    print_list(l2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `create_list` do? Work on a [mcve].

Comment: You forgot to show us the structure definitions. See [mcve].

Comment: For one thing `data_aux` isn't pointing to valid memory, and for another you should use `data_aux` not `&data_aux` in `memcpy`.

Comment: The question is about a run time problem.  When asking about a run time problem, post a [mcve]  Otherwise the question is 'off-topic'.  Be sure to post the `#include` statements

Comment: OT: regarding: `int
main(int argc, char *argv[])`  Since the parameters are not used, the compiler will output two messages about unused parameters.  When the parameters to `main()` are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: The function: `create_list()` can return NULL.  The code should be checking that returned value.   When a NULL is returned, any accessing of memory as an offset of the NULL can/will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;`  Always inform the user of the failure.  This is typically done via: `perror( "malloc failed" )`  Which will output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   The first reason is that `List` is not defined.  Suggest replacing all occurrences of  `List`  with `struct list`

Comment: where is the function: `insert_list()`  It would be especially useful to know how the function: `insert_list()` is handling that dummy entry that was created in the function: `create_list()`

Comment: OT:  in general, when a field is to point to the next 'node'  Then for clarity, that field is named `next`

Comment: OT: regarding the function: `cpy_list()`  1) the only value it can return is `1` so it could easily have a return type of `void`.   This suggestion is reinforced by the `main()` function failing to check the returned value

Comment: regarding: `void *data_aux;` and `memcpy(&data_aux, iter->data, sizeof(iter->data));`  The variable: `data_aux` contains what ever trash was on the stack at the location of the variable.  So it is unknown where that data is being copied to. (unless you meant it to be copied to where `data_aux` is located, in which case the stack will be corrupted from that data being copied to it.)   So the result is undefined behavior and can/will result in a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `while (iter != head->end) {
        ...
    }
    printf("\"%s\"", iter->data);`   When this call to `printf()` is executed, the variable: `iter` will contain a NULL.   so `iter->data` will be accessing memory slightly offset from address 0.  Not what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `memcpy(&data_aux, iter->data, sizeof(iter->data));`

I'll assume this is a typo problem (let me know if it is not and you intended to use it like that). `&data_aux` will return the address of variable `data_aux`, not the address *pointed by* `data_aux`. This code is likely causing a stack overflow as you are probably 
writing data beyond the boundaries of the local variable `data_aux` (which have the size of a pointer - 4 bytes on x86 or 8 bytes on x64). If `iter->data` have a significant size you will corrupt the stack and have undefined behavior.

What you probably want is to allocate a buffer to be pointed by `data_aux`. Something like:

```
data_aux = malloc(sizeof(iter->data));
```

And then pass `data_aux` instead of `&data_aux` in your call to `memcpy`.